# Problema con código else y elseif

Tags: php, condiciones, else

deseo mostrar mostrar en una línea un determinado texto en dependencia del día y la hora en cada semana. Tengo este código pero no encuentro el error, me muestra como resultado solo la primera opción "1".

```
    <?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Havana');
$currentDate = date('N, H:i');
if($currentDate >= date('1, 00:00') || $currentDate < date('1, 02:30'))
 { echo "1";}
elseif ($currentDate >= date('1, 02:30') || $currentDate < date('1, 03:00'))
 {echo "2";}
elseif ($currentDate >= date('1, 03:00') || $currentDate < date('1, 06:00'))
 {echo "3";}
elseif ($currentDate >= date('1, 06:00') || $currentDate < date('1, 06:30'))
 {echo "4";}
elseif ($currentDate >= date('1, 06:30') || $currentDate < date('1, 08:30'))
 {echo "5";}
elseif ($currentDate >= date('4, 23:20') || $currentDate < date('4, 23:59'))
 {echo "6";}
else
  {echo "Loko";}
?>
```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es saber si una fecha está comprendida dentro de un intervalo, quizás es un && (AND) lo que necesitas en lugar de || (OR). Siempre se va a cumplir la primera condición de tu primer if tal y como lo tienes ahora, de ahí que siempre devuelva 1

Answer (score 1):

ciertamente el error estaba en el uso de || por &&

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Havana');
$currentDate = date('N, H:i');
if($currentDate >= date('1, 00:00') && $currentDate < date('1, 02:30'))
 { echo "1";}
elseif ($currentDate >= date('1, 02:30') && $currentDate < date('1, 03:00'))
 {echo "2";}
elseif ($currentDate >= date('1, 03:00') && $currentDate < date('1, 06:00'))
 {echo "3";}
elseif ($currentDate >= date('5, 00:00') && $currentDate < date('5, 06:30'))
 {echo "4";}
elseif ($currentDate >= date('1, 06:30') && $currentDate < date('1, 08:30'))
 {echo "5";}
elseif ($currentDate >= date('3, 00:20') && $currentDate < date('3, 01:59'))
 {echo "6";}
?>
```

ya me funcionó...